# How can we cast the column that contains values of multiple types to single data type using glue dynamic dataframe python

Tags: python, dynamic, aws-glue

How can we cast the column that contains values of multiple types to single data type. I am using resolveChoice method but still it doesn't convert the multple types to single data type using glue dynamic dataframe python.

**code**

```
df = df.resolveChoice(specs=[("Offset", "cast:long")])
```

**Input schema**

```
- dec: array
-- element: struct
    |-- Offset: choice
    |    |-- long
    |    |-- string
```

**Current Output Schema**

```
- dec: array
-- element: struct
    |-- Offset: choice
    |    |-- long
    |    |-- string
```

**Expected Output Schema**

```
dec: array
    -- element: struct
        |-- Offset: long
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to input the whole "path" of the property:

```
df = df.resolveChoice(specs=[("dec[].Offset", "cast:long")])
```